# Share common typescript code across node projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, shared-libraries

Assuming I have the following project structure:

- webapps

  - ProjectA

    - SomeClass.ts
    - Package.json
  - ProjectB

    - SomeClass.ts
    - Package.json
  - Common

    - LoggingClass.ts
    - Package.json

The Common "LoggingClass" need to import a module from NPM. Let's assume that module is UUID (https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

The problem, or the challenge is the following: We want to use and import the "LoggingClass" in both ProjectA and ProjectB.

Thing is, they can import the code from the common folder without a problem, but then the module "UUID" is not existent in those project because we did not specify so in their own respective **Package.json**.

I do not want to create actual node modules since my code needs to be checked into a git repository. (Some people recommend to develop directly into node_modules directory).

I would like to know what other fellow typescript developers do in the community to share their code when using npm. (If it was only typescript files it wouldn't be a problem, but because of the dependencies we have on npm.. it gets complicated).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: `Some people recommend to develop directly into node_modules directory` NOOOO!

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to create actual node modules since my code needs to be checked into a git repository.

A real npm module is actually a way to go IMHO. You don't have to store it specifically in `npmjs.org` (you can have an own npm repository).

> Some people recommend to develop directly into node_modules directory.

This is actually the most inconvenient way I can imagine of. Probably, I'm missing something important, but I'd love to know their way of thinking.

There are things you will not be able to [easily] achieve with git-only based solution. For example, how would you checkout a specific version of the shared code, with keeping the rest of the code intact? It is *relatively* easy when you have only one directory where all the shared code lives. But if you have many (basically, directories-as-packages) then it gets cumbersome. And even figuring out their "versions" is tricky too -- you'd have to invent and follow a git tagging rule or some other way to annotate commits.

Anyways, what I am trying to say is that my answer is not exactly what you asked for; my answer is rather a suggestion to reassess you position regarding (not) packing code into an npm module -- which is *de facto a standard* in the JavaScript/TypeScript community *for a reason*.

Comment: Do you have an example of that ?
I tried to dodge the node module because of the inconvenience to develop inside the node_modules directory. If we can do that differently, then that might become an option. Also, it is possible to create private npm modules ?

Comment: `npm module -- which is de facto a standard in the JavaScript/TypeScript community` so let's say I have shared `StudentLib` and I want to edit one line there. Do I need to republish the package and then update in each project?? This is the worst solution so far, if this is the `standard in the JavaScript/TypeScript community` that says a lot

Comment: *You don't have to store it specifically in npmjs.org (you can have an own npm repository).*

How does this work if you're using a CI system, like Netlify, where you push to git and it auto-deploys? I'd be happy to use `npm link` if this were somehow portable to somewhere other than my dev machine without having to publish to NPM.

Answer (score -2):

> I would like to know what other fellow typescript developers do in the community to share their code when using npm

Since your requirement `I do not want to create actual node modules since my code needs to be checked into a git repository.`

I would simply reorganize as

- webapps

  - package.json
  - projectA

    - SomeClass.ts
  - projectB

    - SomeClass.ts
    - Package.json
  - common

    - LoggingClass.ts

Comment: If I understand well, you added a package.json file to the root. 
How does that work at compile time ? We have some node_modules in a higher folder, and some other node_modules in a lower folder