# Code organization: Node server and react project with shared types

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

### Question

I have

1. a straightforward react client, and
2. a node server that serves the client pages and acts as an API for the client.

They are tightly-coupled, independent TypeScript projects that are part of one larger `git` repo. The server will never be "deployed" anywhere, it just will run on the local network.

I want to keep a shared set of types that define the API. Something like how [RESTyped](https://github.com/rawrmaan/restyped-giphy-api/blob/master/giphy-api.d.ts) defines them:

```js
interface MyAPIDefinition {
  "/user/": {
    "GET": {
      params: { id: number }
      response: { ... }
    }
    ...
  }
  "/image/:id": {
  ...
}
```

*Note*: Some of these types may be dependent on `@types/node`, e.g. `Buffer`.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

### Research so far

1. [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58277554/3554391) suggests merging everything into one project, with the server at the root and the client as a subfolder. The downsides I see with this are:

   - The complexity of getting `react-scripts build|run` to work on the subfolder
   - (More importantly IMO) the server and client are sharing their `node_modules`
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701956/3554391) suggests using yarn workspaces. In my case I would use [npm workspaces](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0026-workspaces.md) I guess, but that seems to be bleeding-edge tooling that I would rather not mess with, as it could cause confusion among my team.
3. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883766/3554391) says to throw away the simplicity of a directory-based workflow and package your `shared` code/types into a privately-hosted npm module. This seems like a huge pain, since a) the server and client are part of a single repo, so the shared code should live there too, and b) I would have to republish the package and reupdate the dependencies in both modules whenever I wanted to make changes. This would also be a complicated workflow to explain to my collaborators.
4. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50993487/3554391) wasn't answered but has a few updates from the OP. They ended up writing a script which watches the files in the shared directory and automatically copies them to the other projects. This feels hacky and confusing to collaborators.

Comment: 3 is the official answer and will serve for sharing beyond this app. 2 is a solution to 3's overhead (from [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)). 1 I would avoid. 4 seems like [link](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/) with extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you already use some kind of monorepo containing projects for your back and front.

Tools such as [rush](https://rushjs.io/) or [nx](https://nx.dev/latest/node/getting-started/why-nx) allows you to automatize monorepo project inter-dependencies / publishing / build...

The back and front project could depend on a new shared "interfaces" project and the monorepo tool would wire everything and handle dependency bump and such.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any reason I shouldn't just `npm install ../shared` in the server/client? Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089029/3554391) answer.